# javascript + coffeescript, with grouping operator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, coffeescript

Is there grouping operator for coffeescript? I'm trying to turn this:

```
var urlParams;
(window.onpopstate = function () {
    var match,
        pl     = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        decode = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " ")); },
        query  = window.location.search.substring(1);

    urlParams = {};
    while (match = search.exec(query))
       urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
})();
```

into coffeescript. I have this so far, but I'm not getting it correct

```
window.onpopstate = ->
  pl     = /\+/g  # Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
  search = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g
  decode = (s) ->
    return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pl, " "))
  query  = window.location.search.substring(1)

  urlParams = {};
  while (match = search.exec(query))
    urlParams[decode(match[1])] = decode(match[2]);
```

Trying to alert, but getting `urlParams is not defined`

```
jQuery ->
  alert(urlParams['hair'])
```

It might be because of the `()` at the end of the function that I'm not getting it?

Comment: Where is that alert? In your coffeescript version, urlParams is only visible inside of the function, in JS it was global.

Comment: @Thilo I updated my post to show where my alert was under

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoffeeScript will declare variables in the scope at their first assignment. Since you first assign `urlParams` within `onpopstate`, that's where it's declared, and is not accessible outside there. To replicate the JavaScript's behavior, you've got to initialize it outside of the `onpopstate` handler:

```
urlParams = null
window.onpopstate = ->
  # ...
```

Note that this assumes that `urlParams` will only be accessed within that one script; since CoffeeScript wraps everything in an IIFE and `urlParams` will be trapped inside it, you cannot access it outside if declared that way. If you want it to be truly global, accessible from other scripts as well, you'll need to replace every occurrence with `window.urlParams`.

A few other things, though:

1. The `()` at the end of the JavaScript version is indeed not there in the CoffeeScript version, although that's not what caused your problem. Fortunately, there's a *very* easy way to do this in CoffeeScript without adding a bunch of parentheses: use `do`:

   ```
   do window.onpopstate = ->
     # ...
   ```
2. Trailing semicolons are not required in CoffeeScript. I'd remove them.
3. That `return` in the definition of `decode` is implicit in CoffeeScript. I'd remove it.
4. Parentheses are not required around the condition of the `while`. I'd remove them.
5. If you'd like, you can take advantage of CoffeeScript's implicit function calls without parentheses, e.g.:

   ```
   while match = search.exec query
   ```

   There's several other places you could apply this too, although for readability's sake I'd only do it where it seems sensible.

Comment: And depending on where the alert is, maybe even `window.urlParams`, otherwise it will only be visible within the compilation unit (coffeescript seals everything in a scope by default).

Comment: "you'll need to replace every occurrence": Technically only every assignment. Lookups would "bubble up" properly. But for the sake of consistency, I'd prefix those, too.

Comment: this really helped my script out. It was the null that I didn't have in the beginning that was causing my script to not execute